# the map overlaps the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I set  the nav as fixed so that when I scroll, it will stick to the top.
but when I scroll through the map, it overlaps into the navigation
here are the codes that I used:

**CSS:**

```html
#container header{
    background-color:white;
    width: 890px;
    padding: 0 0.8em;
    height: 120px;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
}

#map{
    z-index:2px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #eee;
    width: 26%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

**This is what happened**

[image: this is what happened]

Comment: `z-index` doesn't take a unit like `px`. And the `z-index` of the nav should be higher than that of the map.

Comment: i think you need to add higher z-index in navigaton bar (#container header ) as compare to Map (#map) css and yes as @ag_dhruv is right z-index doesn't take unit like px,..

Answer (score 1):

Just make a change in your css:
Remove `px` from `z-index`. z-index creates planes and that are not in px.

```
#map{
    z-index:2;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #eee;
    width: 26%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

If you want that the map does not come over navigation bar, set the z-index of map to be lower than that of navigation bar.